# QGIS Crashes when selecting > Settings>Project Properties

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and this forum but have not found a related problem with a solution.

Running Quantum GIS 1.8.0, on Windows 7 Pro

Running the software, the first action I would normally take on a new project is to set the project properties; however, as soon as I select the project properties option qgis stops working and I get a Windows error reporting notice and QGIS closes.

I have tried re-installing from both the windows installer and the OSGeo4W package and I get the same result every time.

Does Qgis keep an error log?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: can you turn on Log Messages panel and see any shows up there? you can find Log panel here. View -> Panels -> Log Messages

Comment: I get the start up notifications but when the crash occurs nothing has appeared in the log.

Comment: the best thing to this bug is to build from source with a debug flag enabled.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to walk me through that as I am only new to this.

Comment: hmm. yes it will be hard for newbies. But another option is OSGeo4W uses mingw and msys. so running from a cmd line says anything?. Could you load any layers (raster or vector from it)

Comment: Nothing in the cmd prompt when I run qgis from OSGeo and then try changing the project settings, qgis fails. I can load vector and raster layers but have now discovered if I try to set the layer CRS that also causes qgis to fail, but setting project CRS from the layer does not appear to cause a problem, but I can't check if it is doing anything.

Comment: try removing osgeo4w completely and install qgis from this http://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-1.8.0-1-Setup.exe. what are your current CRS settings. `Settings -> Options -> CRS`. when you add a layer does it asks for CRS?

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted the issue,

I guess while changing settings something got corrupted; an uninstall/reinstall did not fix this, so after an uninstall I manually deleted all references to Quantum, OSGeo and Python in the windows registry, re-installed and everything works again.

Thanks for your patience and help rashad.